# Secure USB Drive by creating 2 partitions one is read only

Tags: usb, security, partitioning, usb-flash-drive

i have a Lexar 8GB flash drive and i want to protect it using some software i forgot it's name o anything about it ! .

The software creates 2MB (i think) partition on the drive and the rest of the drive becomes an encrypted partition (so physically the drives will have 2 partitions)

the 2MB partition is READ ONLY and has one executable file , when when launched asks for a password and unlocks the 2nd partition after mounting it .

does anybody know this software , or something similar ?

Comment: This sounds very similar to an inbuilt feature of an old usb stick I have. It essentially switches modes on the stick, so it's not something that can be installed on a drive. There may be a program that does this, but I doubt it, as Windows doesn't support multiple partitions on usb devices normally and the software would have to install a driver to mount the extra partition.

Answer (score 2):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is very secure disk encryption software.

Comment: Also, if you install this in [Portable Mode](http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=truecrypt-portable) and create a container on the stick it behaves almost exactly like the program in question. (The container is visible and the drive isn't read only though.)

Comment: I would recommend TrueCrypt too, but beware that you need administrator privileges in order to run it.

Comment: the problem is , what if you or someone else formatted that partition ... woopa everything's gone !